# Jasmine AG Grid Test case failed

Tags: jasmine, ag-grid-angular, angular-test

Am trying to write a test for ag grid export method.
Here is the component changes

```
export class GridComponent extendsimplements OnInit {

  gridApi: any;

  onGridDataExport(): void {
    this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv();
  }
}
```

**grid component spec file**

```
fdescribe('when onGridDataExport method call', () => {
    it('should call gridApi', () => {
      const result = spyOn(component.gridApi, 'exportDataAsCsv');
      component.onGridDataExport();
      expect(result).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
```

when i run the test cases it show the below error
[image]

How can i resolve this issue?

expecting a valid solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When do you do `this.gridApi = ...`? Make sure that is done in the unit test before `component.onGridDataExport()`.

Comment: i have added const params = {exportDataAsCsv: {}};
      component.gridApi = params.exportDataAsCsv;.now its showing exportDataAsCsv not a function

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```js
fdescribe('when onGridDataExport method call', () => {
    it('should call gridApi', () => {
      const result = spyOn(component.gridApi, 'exportDataAsCsv').and.callThrough();
      component.onGridDataExport();
      expect(result).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

If you look my code, I'm adding `.and.callThrough();` and you need to use this because with this code you're really waiting for the execution of the method `exportDataAsCsv`.